# Impersonation fails on Apache Drill while having Kerberos enabled

Tags: authentication, jdbc, impersonation, apache-drill

I am using **Apache Drill** terminal interface (`sqlline`) to query various sources like `hdfs` (with `dfs` storage plugin). I have enabled impersonation property and Kerberos authentication and when I connect to 
`Drill` (`./sqlline -u "jdbc:drill:zk=<zookeper_quorum:port>;auth=kerberos"`) and execute a simple query which requires impersonation (`show schemas;`) it is failing with the error :

> **Error: Failure getting metadata: RESOURCE ERROR: Failed to create schema tree.**
>
> IOException:  User: drill/primary@REALM is not allowed to impersonate 
>   [Hint: Username is absent in connection URL or doesn't exist on Drillbit node. Please specify a username in connection URL which is present on Drillbit node.]

Any insights on what might be wrong ? The `drillbit` logs show the same error

Comment: Impersonation requires **special privileges**, and visibly you did not declare `drill` as a "Hadoop proxy user". Just like `hive`, `oozie`, `hue`, `knox`, `zeppelin` etc.

Comment: Plus, the "auth_to_local" rules should have translated the Kerberos SPN used by DrillBits into a plain Linux/Hadoop user name like `drill`.

Comment: I have added drill as one of the users which can be used for impersonation in core-site.xml using hadoop.drill.hosts and hadoop.drill.groups properties with values *

Comment: After days of research for the problem I found the root of it. Specifically there was a storage plugin that I configured on webUI of hdfs from another cluster in which drill and my user didn't have the permissions to access. By disabling this plugin everything went back to normal for all the other storage plugins with the impersonation enabled!